# Copying std::vector of primitive types behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, language-lawyer, memcpy

**Background:**

When copying a `std::vector` using its copy constructor or copy assignment like this:

```
std::vector<T> v1{T(),T(),T()};
std::vector<T> v2 = v1;
```

a deep copy happens.

Is it guaranteed by the standard that the copy constructor of `T` will be triggered for each element? In other words no `memcpy` (or something similar) will be called. (Correct me if I am wrong).

**Question:**

On the other hand, is it guaranteed by the standard that it would call  `memcpy` (or something similar) on primitive types (for performance issues)?

Comment: "Is it guaranteed by the standard that the copy constructor of the T will be triggered for each element?" - definitely. How else can it behave? Why do you even ask?

Comment: It would be crazy not calling the copy constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `T`'s copy constructor must be called. If the copy constructor is trivial, it's effect is the exact same as that of `memcpy`, so an implementation is fine to use the latter to *implement* that copy constructor. From there on, the implementation may decide to use `memcpy` to implement the copy constructor of `vector`. That decision makes use of the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if): The program's observable behavior remains unchanged, hence we need not actually perform all the copy constructor calls.

> On the other hand, does it guaranteed by the standard that it would
>   call  memcpy (or something similar) on primitive types (for
>   performance issues)?

No, because how a copy constructor is actually implemented is an implementation detail. The standard merely specifies a program's (observable) behavior, and it does that using the notion of copy constructors etc. Optimization is nothing an abstract standard document should worry about, but your vendor. In fact, restraining the definitions of such functions would either incur a huge deficit in optimization, or be outright ignored due to the aforementioned as-if rule.

Answer (score 2):

The exact code generated for copy construction of primitive types is a quality of implementation issue. In other words, the standard will not **guarantee** anything of the sort - at best, it will specify the algorithmic complexity of the operation, in this case copying of the vector can be inferred as `O(n)`.

With modern C++ compilers on a reasonable optimization setting, you can count on copy construction of POD classes being implemented in-line, as efficiently as a constant-size `memcpy`. Doing anything else would incur serious penalties with typical use cases, such as STL containers of pointers.